# Como gerar um grafico com uma curva semelhante ao "seno" em jquery flot?

Tags: jquery, flot

Amigos,

Estou usando o flot para um projetinho de **simulacao de ECG (eletrocardiograma)**, e dei de cara com um problema, que acho que eh mais de **matematica do que de programacao**...

Entao desculpem se estou explicando mau.
BOM, meu problema eh fazer a transicao do batimento normal, para maior! (ou seja o que acontece quando se aplica o medicamento)

**Por exemplo:**
O batimento  esta em 70, e aplico adrenalina, e este deve ir a 210.

Fazer isso em linha reta eh tranquilo, como neste exemplo:**(exemplo do proprio flot)** (que vai de "6M" ate "TE")

- [Por favor veja o codigo de exemplo no fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Yamamila/5zmxc5Lu/40/)
  [image: Exemplo de transicao em linha reta, basta somar 1 para high]

Mas eu preciso se que seja uma forma de onda como um "seno"  como este:**(que vai de "6M" ate "TE")**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**EIS minha questao para o float:**

- Simplificando a pergunta, como eu faria no [jquery flot (em realtime)](http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/realtime/index.html), para gerar um grafico que comeca em X e vai ate Y, com uma "curva" semelhante a um seno?

Comment: Se você conseguir fazer um [mcve] ou ao menos [edit] sua pergunta e colar o trecho de código que gera a rampa reta, fica mais fácil para ajudarmos com o "easing" da curva. Tem várias maneiras de fazer, mas ajudaria muito partir do seu código já existente. Vale notar que biblioteca de "easing" do jQuery (a mesma usada para animações) é uma boa referência (e talvez até seja o caso de reaproveitar). Basicamente essas fórmulas usam a rampa como entrada (de 0 a 1, por exemplo), e devolvem uma curva logaritmica.

Comment: Editei minha pergunta. Por favor veja o codigo de exemplo no fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/Yamamila/5zmxc5Lu/40/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Em princípio, o que você procura é um Envelope, para modificar a onda principal. Para simplificar as coisas, você pode criar uma função que pegue um valor linear, e transforme numa curva.

Veja um exemplo bem simples:

```
function Easing( i ) {
    i *= 2;
    if (i<1) return 1/(2-i)-.5;
    return 1.5-1/i;
};
```

Se alimentar esta fórmula linearmente com um valor de `0` a `1`, receberá de volta um valor também de `0` a `1`, só que não linear.

O que você precisa fazer, no caso é pegar a amplitude da onda principal, e multiplicar pelo resultado da fórmula.

Segue um exemplo bem básico de uso. O código extenso é para desenhar o canvas, mas o que interessa é apenas a aplicação da fórmula:

```js
function Easing( i ) {
 i *= 2;
 if (i<1) return 1/(2-i)-.5;
 return 1.5-1/i;
};

//demonstração:
var canvas = document.getElementById("out");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d"); 
var width = canvas.width;
var height = canvas.height;
var data;

context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(0,height);
context.strokeStyle = 'red';
for(i=0; i<=100; i++)
{
  data = i/100; //linear
  context.lineTo(i/100*width,height-data*height);
  context.stroke();
}

context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(0,height);
context.strokeStyle = 'blue';
for(i=0; i<100; i++)
{
  data = Easing( i/100 ); //usando função
  context.lineTo(i/100*width,height-data*height);
  context.stroke();
}
```

```css
#out {width:300px; height:200px; border:1px dotted #999}
```

```html
<canvas id="out"></canvas>
```

Teste também no **[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/bacco/pen/gLmbxo)**.

Lembre-se de que o próprio jQuery tem funções de `easing`, que já fazem coisa parecida. Normalmente são usadas para animações, mas nada impede de aplicar em gráficos:

> https://jqueryui.com/easing/

Neste site tem uma série de fórmulas que podem te interessar:

> http://www.gizma.com/easing/

Comment: Estou tentando estudar como usar seu exemplo e,  como são valores fixos, parece funcionar bem mas no meu caso eh uma animação, e estou apanhando pra adaptar,  ja que os valores vão mudando, Na verdade acho que e falta de experiencia minha mesmo. Bom coloquei um exemplo no fiddle como você pediu. mas não consegui criar o tal envelope. ou seja transformar aquela reta em seno.
https://jsfiddle.net/Yamamila/5zmxc5Lu/40/

Comment: @CamilaYamamoto adaptei a função no seu código. Na verdade, para usar envelopes, precisa resolver o conjunto todo, está um pouco complexa demais a função toda, mas aí já foge do foco da pergunta:  https://jsfiddle.net/5zmxc5Lu/44/ - como está um bocado simplificado, se você "desligar" o botão no meio da curva, não vai ficar legal o resultado, precisaria de uma atenuação. Mas se esperar chegar no máximo e clicar de novo, a curva fica razoável. Trocando a fórmula do Easing você muda a forma da curva.

Comment: você é o the best! :D

Comment: estou com mais uma duvida no post http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/168940/como-usar-transicoes-de-tempo-em-uma-animacao-canvas  , quem sabe você saiba como ajudar!  adoro suas  dicas!

Comment: Meu codigo nao ficou igual, mas estudar o codigo que voce deu de exemplo me possibilitou adaptar para minha necessidade!  e consegui fazer!   obrigadaaa!