# Como usar transicoes de "tempo" em uma animacao Canvas

Tags: jquery, canvas, flot

Dando sequencia ao post "[Como gerar uma curva Seno](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/166713/como-gerar-um-grafico-com-uma-curva-semelhante-ao-seno-em-jquery-flot)", onde fiz alguns ajustes:

Ainda estou trabalhando neste simulador de ECG (eletrocardiograma), e agora preciso "manipular" os tempos dentro do simulador,

Por exemplo: Demora muito entre aplicar o medicamento e ficar esperando que ele passe por todo o processo, para conferir os resultados.
Então, criei este botão que "faz o **tempo** passar" com o dobro da velocidade.

- Embora inicialmente esteja FUNCIONADO (E o gráfico fica semelhante), QUANDO troco a velocidade e SOMENTE depois aplico o medicamento.
- Mas, se eu troco essa velocidade "DURANTE" a transição, acontecem coisas loucas nos resultados.
- [por favor confira neste exemplo  do CodePen](http://codepen.io/Yamamila/pen/BQmXRg)   onde eu usei um exemplo do Jquery-flot

Ou seja, não importa a velocidade do tempo, o gráfico sempre deveria ser idêntico.

para isso simplesmente dividi os tempos das variáveis..

> Eis a parte do codigo que cria a onda Seno

```
if(isRunning==true){
                    if( medicineTime1 >= 1 ){
                        medicineTime1--;
                        if( medicineTime1 < 1 ){ medicineTime1 = .1; }
                        //
                        // o  "high2Temp e linear", transformando em "seno"...
                        //
                        // criar o  "envelope" apra ancorar o coeficiente.
                        high2Target  = high2TargetPhase1; 
                        high2Final   = high2Target + high2Temp;
                        high2FinalSum= high2Final / medicineTime1 ;
                        high2Temp    = high2Temp - high2FinalSum; 
                        // criar o coeficiente.
                        coefficient =  ( high2FinalSum / high2TempTimeG );
                        //  para dividir em 2  (metades), durante o tempo de "de subida". 
                        if( !isMedicineTime1Temp ){ 
                            medicineTime1Temp = medicineTime1; 
                            // assumindo que sempre partiremos de  "Normal ECG"
                            // high2Inicial = 70; 
                            high2Inicial = high2;
                            isMedicineTime1Temp = true;
                        } 
                        //  primeira metade
                        if( medicineTime1 > medicineTime1Temp / 2 ){
                            apple = apple + coefficient;    
                            high2 = high2 - apple;
                        }                           
                        //  segunda metade
                        if( medicineTime1 < medicineTime1Temp / 2 ){
                            apple = apple - coefficient;    
                            high2 = high2 - apple;
                        }
                        //
                        // a frequencia sempre sera  linear...
                        //
                        frequency2Target  = frequency2TargetPhase1/frequency2Factor;
                        frequency2Final   = frequency2Target-frequency2;
                        frequency2FinalSum= frequency2Final/medicineTime1 ;
                        frequency2        = frequency2 + frequency2FinalSum;
                        if(medicineTime1<1){
                            //high2 = high2TargetPhase1 * -1; 
                            frequency2         = frequency2TargetPhase1/frequency2Factor;
                            medicinePhase1     = false;
                            medicinePhase2     = true;
                            isMedicineTime1Temp= false;
                        }
                    }
}
```

> E aqui como divido as variáveis:

```
document.getElementById('buttonTime1').onclick = function(){
    updateInterval = updateInterval*2;
    medicineTime1 = medicineTime1*2;
    high2TempTimeG = 50;
    document.getElementById("log").innerHTML = "tempo = 1 ";
};
document.getElementById('buttonTime2').onclick = function(){
    updateInterval = updateInterval/2;
    medicineTime1 = medicineTime1/2;
    high2TempTimeG = 25;
    document.getElementById("log").innerHTML = "<font color=red> tempo = 5 </font>";
};
```

Logo eis a minha duvida, por que o código funciona em uma situação, e não na segunda? ja que todas as variáveis sao as mesmas?

o que não estou vendo? onde tenho que prestar atenção?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Percebi onde estava meu erro,

A var "medicineTime1Temp" que e o tempo em que "deve durar" a transição, estava sendo ajustada apenas "antes" da animação iniciar....

Se a velocidade for trocada "durante a aminação", ela também devera ser ajustada,  mas eu havia esquecido.